# Nuxt apollo authentication

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo

I try to build an an authentication with nuxt and apollo.
The login and signup is pretty easy, also to set up the jwt token,  but when my token expire and I try to get a refresh token or to logout my user I getting following error.

```
Invariant Violation
Store reset while query was in flight (not completed in link chain)
```

Because my Error handler which I define in my `nuxt.config.js` do not work I try to build my own client.

So I set at `apollo.clientConfigs.default` my `~/graphql/config.ts` which looks like

```js
export default ({ app }: Context) => {
  const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
      graphQLErrors.map(async (err) => {
        if (err?.extensions?.exception.status === 401) {
          await app.$apolloHelpers.onLogout()
        }

        return err
      })

      return forward(operation)
    }

    if (networkError) {
      console.log(networkError, 'and another one!')
      return forward(operation)
    }

    return forward(operation)
  })

  return {
    httpEndpoint: 'http://localhost:3001/graphql',
    link: from([errorLink as any])
  }
}
```